# What is the right way to get current login user in Camel CXFRS (using spring security)?

Tags: java, spring-security, apache-camel

I use camel cxfrs component to build the REST API. Below is the snippet of the camel route.

```
<route>
    <from
        uri="cxfrs://bean://circulationRsServer?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer" />
    <!-- We can remove this configure as the CXFRS producer is using the HttpAPI 
        by default -->
    <setHeader headerName="CamelCxfRsUsingHttpAPI">
        <constant>True</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <recipientList>
        <simple>direct:circulation.${header.operationName}</simple>
    </recipientList>
    <removeHeaders pattern="*" />
</route>
<route>
    <from uri="direct://circulation.updatePatron" />
    <to
        uri="bean:patronBean?method=update(${header.patronIdentifier})" />
</route>
```

I used Spring Security to secure the REST API.

In patronBean, I use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` to get current login user. 
If I changed the component from `direct` to `seda`, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` return null. It is because seda is running in different independent thread.

So, is it right to get current login user using stateful context(as my code written)? or should I changed all the services to stateless design?

Please provide sample implementation or reference link for stateless design if there is any.

You can download sample project from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1a6gDS5vsQ6cExPVUc1REpYQVU/edit?usp=sharing

It is a maven project. There is a readme.txt to give instruction to test the project.

Comment: You could simply extract authentication from spring holder at beginning of your route and set it as message property. Then you can pass it into your `patronBean` call as another argument

Comment: It is a workable solution but make all the bean method need to accept current login user as parameter. Is it the right way to change the service into stateless service?,

Comment: I just want to ask how did you setup the cxfrs authentication?

Comment: @WillemJiang, I updated the question. I created a sample project to illustrate the problem. It is a maven project. You can download from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1a6gDS5vsQ6cExPVUc1REpYQVU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the code, you used the spring security to protected the cxf service.
If you read about the document of the spring security you can find the it store the security context as a thread local object. When you use the seda endpoint, the exchange is processed in another thread and it can explain why you cannot get the right security context this time.

You can store the security context into the exchange properties map before routing the message to a seda endpoint, and camel always copy the exchange properties no matter which thread could be use to process the exchange.

Comment: You are right. Security Context is bound to the thread. Is it means that I need to refactor my bean method to accept current login user as method parameter?